# How to align content to top

Tags: html, css

I have next [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jfxjuf5/). You can see that second block placed is not in top. how to fix it?

html is -

```
<div id="test1">
    <div id="ct1">
        <img width="100px" height="100px">
        <div id="cct1">
            123123 12312312 3123123123
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ct2">
        <img width="100px" height="100px">
        <div id="cct2">
            123123 12312312
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

styles -

```
#test1{
    margin-top:300px;
}
#test1>div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
}
#test1>div>div{
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: did you try to decrease the margin value?

Comment: @MohamedShawky decreasing margin do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use vertical align property: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4jfxjuf5/3/)**

```
#test1>div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Tanks @G.L.P its best answer for my solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `inline-block` actually fits your blocks to the line, aligned in the bottom by default. A `float: left;` is one of the solutions to fix your issue. *@g-l-p*'s solution with `vertical-align` is an other good option.

```
#test1>div{
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RedBreast/4jfxjuf5/1/

Comment: Tanks for reply. Ur answer is informative. But G.L.P's solution more suitable for me. +1 to U.

Comment: I also think @g-l-p solution is actually more suitable to your issue. Just keep that in mind for a future case, it's sometimes easier to control big blocks/container with `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this -

```
#test1>div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

to your existing CSS

Answer (score 1):

Just update following  css -

```
#test1>div{
  float: left;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Please see updated - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jfxjuf5/7/)

Also using `vertical-align:top;` css see - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jfxjuf5/8/)